# How to do partial derivatives with functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let
$$U(x,t)=f(x+ct)$$
where $f$ is a differentiable function and $c\neq0$

How would I obtain $\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$?

Comment: By using the chain rule - what are your attempts?

Comment: I suspected the chain rule was involved, but just didn't know which form of the rule to use

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (x+ct)}\dfrac{\partial (x+ct)}{\partial t}=c\cdot f'.$$

In which $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x+ct$.

Can you try the same method for the second derivative $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?